# Open link in another tab with e.force:navigateToURL

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, url, navigation

I would open a link in a lightning component in another tab. Here is the code:

```
showAttachment : function(component, event, helper) {
    var idContentVersion = event.getSource().get("v.title");

    console.log(idContentVersion);

    var action = component.get("c.viewContentDocument"); 

    action.setParams({
        idContentVersion: idContentVersion
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var status = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && status === "SUCCESS") {

            event.getSource().set("v.value", "one/one.app#/sObject/ContentDocument/"+response.getReturnValue());

            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
              "url": "one/one.app#/sObject/ContentDocument/" + response.getReturnValue(),
              "target": "_blank"
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error: ' + status);                
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
}
```

I tried to add `"target": "_blank"` as event's parameters but it doesn't work.
This method is called by clicking on a link:
`<ui:outputUrl aura:id="urlFile" label="" value="" target="_blank" click="{!c.showAttachment}"/>`.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understand, the navigation event will use the same window/tab if you give it a URL inside your salesforce instance. So, to get what you want, I think you could just use plain JS:

```
window.open("one/one.app#/sObject/ContentDocument/" + response.getReturnValue(), '_blank');
```

Sounds like you really do want a new window/tab, but in case you haven't seen it, there is an event you fire to preview Content in a lightbox kind of thing:

```
lightning:OpenFiles
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_openFiles.htm