# Make Cmd-Click (Open in tab) work on onclick buttons and links

Tags: lightning, keyboard

As I understand it right we are supposed to not use `href="/..."` attributes anymore in Lightning and have `onclick="{c.navigateToSObject}"` instead.

```
navigateToSObject: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        event.currentTarget.id;
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        evt.setParams({
            "recordId": recordId,
            "slideDevName": "detail"
        });
        evt.fire(); 
    }
```

But how do I get **Command-Click** (on Mac) to work with that?

*According to this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000CIt7AAG it seems to be possible and is perfectly working for all links generated by the Salesforce UI. Just CMD-click any lookup field on a record page.*

Answer (score -1):

Here is example how to detect if CTRL key is pressed:
[Any way to detect keyup and keydown events NOT using an input field?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147024/any-way-to-detect-keyup-and-keydown-events-not-using-an-input-field)

You can also use Salesforce url like here: [Open link in another tab with e.force:navigateToURL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170807/open-link-in-another-tab-with-e-forcenavigatetourl)

I did not try on mac, but on windows this works for me:

```
if(event.ctrlKey) {
    window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');
} else {
    window.location.assign('https://www.google.com');
}
```

If you want to navigate to sObject, use url like this:

```
one/one.app#/sObject/0060E00000XXXXXXXX
```

If you want to navigate to custom component, you can do some trick to get url. In your url `one/one.app#eyJjb...` symbols after `#` is base64 json that decoded 
looks like this:

```
{
    "a:t": 1496392690947, // time when opened
    "attributes": {
        "values": {
            // your component attributes
            }
        }
    },
    "componentDef": "c:YourComponent"
}
```

So you can try to generate your json data, base64 encode and redirect to it.

To see your url decoded and parsed in lightning app, try this:

```
JSON.parse(atob(window.location.hash.split('#')[1]))
```

Comment: As I understand the solutions they don't provide the option to open a link in a new tab but enforce it all the time. What I need is a way to open it in a tab when the user does a CMD-Click.

Comment: How would I have to convert my <a onclick="{!c.handler}"> to make that work?

Comment: Does it work if you put code that redirects in handler method in controller?

Comment: Sure. I can do that.

Comment: So what is still the problem?

Comment: Please check the updated code. I am using navigateToSObject. The is no URL I can fumble around with.

Comment: Than use url like this: /one/one.app#/sObject/0060E000003XXXXXXX

Comment: I don't want to hack an URL. I need the safe way of doing this. In all documents they recommend NOT to write URLs on your own but use the provide JS methods instead. I guess that is for a purpose.

Comment: unfortunately I don't see other ways https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm